# How do I convert Dataset to model <T> - for excel data driven tests

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I have fetched data from excel sheet and it is having all the values in Dataset now I ave DataModel type List and I want to return that type and then fetch data but I'm finding difficulty in that

```
public class TestDataModel
{
    public TestDataModel() { }

    [DataNames("TestName")]
    public string TestName { get; set; }

    [DataNames("productId")]
    public int productId { get; set; }

    [DataNames("orderId")]
    public int orderId { get; set; }

    [DataNames("designMethod")]
    public string designMethod { get; set; }

    [DataNames("signedIn")]
    public bool signedIn { get; set; }

    [DataNames("increaseBasketQty")]
    public bool increaseBasketQty { get; set; }

    [DataNames("signedInCMS")]
    public bool signedInCMS { get; set; }

    [DataNames("editable")]
    public bool editable { get; set; }

    [DataNames("_site")]
    public string _site { get; set; }

    [DataNames("paymentOptions")]
    public string paymentOptions { get; set; }

    [DataNames("checkInVoice")]
    public string checkInVoice { get; set; }

    [DataNames("navigateToDesign")]
    public string navigateToDesign { get; set; }

    [DataNames("checkOrderAuthorsie")]
    public string checkOrderAuthorsie { get; set; }

    [DataNames("checkSplitOrder")]
    public string checkSplitOrder { get; set; }

    [DataNames("SiteId")]
    public string SiteId { get; set; }

    [DataNames("SiteUrl")]
    public string SiteUrl { get; set; }

    [DataNames("CultureCode")]
    public string CultureCode { get; set; }

    [DataNames("SiteGroupId")]
    public string SiteGroupId { get; set; }

    [DataNames("NickName")]
    public string NickName { get; set; }

    [DataNames("byCard")]
    public string byCard { get; set; }

    [DataNames("payLater")]
    public string payLater { get; set; }

    [DataNames("sliceIt")]
    public string sliceIt { get; set; }

    [DataNames("portal")]
    public string portal { get; set; }

    [DataNames("delivery")]
    public string delivery { get; set; }

}
```

Function for fetching Data from Excel

```
 public static IList<TestDataModel> GetAllTestData(string keyName)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataNamesMapper<TestDataModel> mapper = new DataNamesMapper<TestDataModel>();
        DataTable dataTableALL = new DataTable();
        List<TestDataModel> persons = new List<TestDataModel>();
        using (var connection = new
                      OdbcConnection(TestDataFileConnection()))
        {
            connection.Open();
            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
            cmd.Connection = connection;

            System.Data.DataTable dtSheet = null;
            dtSheet = connection.GetSchema(OdbcMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables, null);
            foreach (DataRow row in dtSheet.Rows)
            {
                string sheetName = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                if (!sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
                    continue;

                // Query each excel sheet.
                var query = string.Format("select * from [{0}] where TestName = '{1}'", sheetName, keyName);
                cmd.CommandText = query;

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.TableName = sheetName;

                OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                //dataTableALL.Merge(dt);
                //ds.Merge(dt);
                ds.Tables.Add(dt);


            }
            cmd = null;
            connection.Close();
        }
        DataTable flatTable = null;
        string ID = "TestName";

        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[i];


            if (i == 0)
            {
                flatTable = dt.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();
            }
            else
            {
                DataColumn[] columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
                foreach (DataColumn col in columns)
                {
                    if (col.ColumnName != ID)
                    {
                        flatTable.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
                    }
                }

                var joins = from t1 in flatTable.AsEnumerable()
                            join t2 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                            on t1.Field<string>(ID) equals t2.Field<string>(ID)
                            select new { t1 = t1, t2 = t2 };
                foreach (var join in joins)
                {
                    foreach (string column in columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName))
                    {
                        if (column != ID)
                        {
                            join.t1[column] = join.t2[column];
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            //return testDataModelList.ToList();
            //return ds;
        }
        var test = mapper.Map(dataTableALL).ToList();
        //persons = mapper.Map(ds.Tables[0]).ToList();
        persons = mapper.Map(flatTable).ToList();
        return persons.ToList();
    }
```

In above function I'm not able to understand how do I convert the DS values to TestDataModel List for return

Function Call:

```
var param = AccessExcelData.GetAllTestData<TestDataModel>("BOL_GB_PlaceOrder_By_PayLater_Using_Klarna_With_BillingAddress_Excel");
```

Comment: Do you want to use Entity (which maps excel to classes) or use OLEDB connection?  If you are using OLEDB and putting data into a DataSet ii is probably not necessary to put data into a class.  The DataTable is equivalent to using a class.

Comment: Yes From excel dataset it maps to entity - if that can be done it would be really great

Comment: If mapping will be done then I don't have to access data like Dataset[0].Row[""].value...instead I can directly access by model value

Comment: You either use Entity or OleDb.  VS will automatically create the class if you use Entity from excel.

Comment: Okay so from my above code - What change I can do to have used values from excel in my c# code

Comment: You already have to data in the dataset.  If you put a break point on the return ds (F11) and then hover over the variable ds you will see a down arrow.  Select arrow and the Select DataSet Visualizer.

Comment: My Dataset is having 4 tables and now I have merged it 1 table but the issue is coming that It is showing all rows from various tables in 1 table but I want to have only 1 row having Key name 

ds.Merge(dt);

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;



namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt1.Columns.Add("ColA", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("ColB", typeof(string));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "100", "1000" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "101", "1001" });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "102", "1002" });
            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("ColC", typeof(string));
            dt2.Columns.Add("ColD", typeof(string));

            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "200", "2000" });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "201", "2001" });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "302", "2002" });
            ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

            DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
            dt3.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt3.Columns.Add("ColE", typeof(string));
            dt3.Columns.Add("ColF", typeof(string));

            dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "300", "3000" });
            dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "301", "3001" });
            dt3.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "302", "3002" });
            ds.Tables.Add(dt3);

            DataTable dt4 = new DataTable();
            dt4.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt4.Columns.Add("ColG", typeof(string));
            dt4.Columns.Add("ColH", typeof(string));

            dt4.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "400", "4000" });
            dt4.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "401", "4001" });
            dt4.Rows.Add(new object[] { 3, "402", "4002" });
            ds.Tables.Add(dt4);


            DataTable flatTable = null;
            string ID = "ID";

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables[i];


                if (i == 0)
                {
                    flatTable = dt.AsEnumerable().CopyToDataTable();
                }
                else
                {
                    DataColumn[] columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in columns)
                    {
                        if (col.ColumnName != ID)
                        {
                            flatTable.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, col.DataType);
                        }
                    }

                    var joins = from t1 in flatTable.AsEnumerable()
                                join t2 in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                on t1.Field<int>(ID) equals t2.Field<int>(ID)
                                select new { t1 = t1, t2 = t2 };
                    foreach (var join in joins)
                    {
                        foreach (string column in columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName))
                        {
                            if (column != ID)
                            {
                                join.t1[column] = join.t2[column];
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }


            }
            string[] filteredColumns = { "ColA", "ColC", "ColE", "ColG" };
            int[] filteredIndexes = filteredColumns.Select(x => flatTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(y => x == y.ColumnName).First().Ordinal).ToArray();

            DataTable filteredTable = new DataTable();
            foreach (int index in filteredIndexes)
            {
                filteredTable.Columns.Add(flatTable.Columns[index].ColumnName, flatTable.Columns[index].DataType);
            }
            foreach(DataRow row in flatTable.AsEnumerable())
            {
                filteredTable.Rows.Add(filteredIndexes.Select(y => row[y]).ToArray());
            };

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216264/discussion-on-answer-by-jdweng-how-do-i-convert-dataset-to-model-t-for-excel).

Comment: @jdweng can u plz check

Comment: Looks like PaymentOptions1 properties are commented out from Saturdays Chat.  Where did following come from : [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

Comment: I used from existing code..I had mentioned the code to "chat"

Comment: I somehow not understanding - since now I received values in one row but i just want acess few columns as object.column

Comment: @jdweng if you can suggest any approach

Comment: If you only want certain columns you can make a List<string> of column names and then copy these columns to a new table.   Or copy existing table to new table and delete columns you do not need.

Comment: the thing is I want all the columns which we fetched in flattable - but now instead of accessing it as flatable.columnname - I want some mechanism for fetching few columns where I can access them as flattable.anotherobject.columnname @jdweng

Comment: @jdweng any thoughts?

Comment: Didn't get to finish changes yesterday.  I just updated Dynamic code to create a new table with selected columns.

Comment: I'll try your updated code @jdweng - Thank you so much :)

Comment: I changed one instruction filteredIndexes so the columns are in the same order as filteredColumns.  The original code made the order the same order as flatTable.

Comment: hey @jdweng - I tried your code and yes now I get filtered column but how do I add in flattable and access like flattabel.filteredtable.columname

Comment: I think you are asking at runtime how do a choose the columns.  You can put all the columns names into a list box and then let user choose the columns.

Comment: @jdweng - No, what I want is I Flattable - with all the coulmns, We have also filtered few columns now I want to use columns of filtered table in flattable as 

Flattabel.FilteredTable.ColumnName (so i can have those filtered table column access like this)

Comment: What is the difference between the flat table and the filtered table?  They are both DataTables.  So I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: So Flat Table is one where all the coulmns from different sheet are joined in one table

And filtered table is one where we extracted few columns from flat table

Now I want is from to access filtered table's columns from Flattable.FilteredTable.Column

Comment: So are you looking to join the two tables so from the filtered table you can get the additional columns that you removed?  Remember the row number are the same from the two tables.

Comment: I have one function:

var param1 = AccessExcelData.GetAllTestData("Test1");

This is having code which you written above to fetch data from multiple sheet to one sheet in one row

Currently all the columns are accessible with param[0].columnname

Now what I wanted is for few columns I want to access it as

param[0].object.column

Comment: Yeah so I want to  add table in FlatTable, so I can access Filtered table's column with FlatTable.FilteredTable.Column

Comment: filteredTable.AsEnumerable().Select((x, i) => flatTable.Rows[i][7]);

Comment: I did not understand what it will do, I added above line after our function but look like still same - how do I access flattable.filteredtable.column :(

Comment: What is the row index?  How would you get the particular row?

Comment: here is the code for which i want such an implementation https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1g-_4H8jW9O_uhNFeYw1eG8r-IPhEAtDW?usp=sharing

Comment: string[] filteredColumns = { "payLater", "portal", "delivery" };
            int[] filteredIndexes = filteredColumns.Select(x => flatTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(y => x == y.ColumnName).First().Ordinal).ToArray();

Comment: I got it as per your code..passed the column name and row is 1

Comment: Flattable won't have multiple rows - as we have already fetched the data and now it will have only one row in table

Comment: So you either need to do following 1) capture row number from original table 2) Join or Where by unique ID the two tables.

Comment: Okay but in join or where by - how will I be able to access flattable.filteredtable.columnname...confused  :(

Can you help me with any example?

Comment: DataRow row = filteredtable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("TestName") == "abc").First(); string orderId = row["orderId"];

Comment: @jdweng - in filtered table i've not fetched testname column value... it has values for  { "payLater", "portal", "delivery" };

So flattable has few column values which I want and Filteredtable also has some column values which I want and both the tables have only one row as expected

So from above code how will I be able to retrieve column values like

flattable.filteredtable.payLater

Comment: There is only two ways 1) Save the row number(s) so you can get the data from original table or lookup by a unique ID.

Comment: not sure how am i gonna do that as i'm really confused on the part how will i access as flattable.filteredtable.columnname

this is just tough for me to get :(

Comment: so far I am retrieving values of columns like flattable.orderId, flattable.payLater

But the only concern point is that I want to retrieve data as flatable.filteredtable.payLater

Comment: @jdweng - I understood the problem - my mapper is not converting the column values to custom property type - can you plz look if you can https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619617/issue-in-mapping-property-from-excel-data-table-to-list

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var testDataModelList = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
   .Select(dataRow => new TestDataModel
   {
       TestName = dataRow.Field<string>("TestName"),
       productId = (int)dataRow["productId"],
       ...
   }).ToList();
```

Comment: You can try ```int productId = (int)dataRow["productId"];``` if you're unable to cast directly.