# How to export Linq List to Excel Range

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, linq

I have a list converted from Json having approximately 26 fields. Among those fields I need to select a few as below

```
 var use = Data.USEData.Where(x => x.GLMBorrowerName == borrowerName)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Date)
                .Select(c => new
                {
                    USDBalance = c.Sum(x => x.USDBalance),
                    Commitment = c.Sum(x => x.Commitment),
                    Date = c.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault().Date
                }).ToList();
```

There are four objects each having different fields.

Once these objects are returned by function, I need to export them into excel range.

I am unable to find a generic type which can converted dynamically into array so that it can be exported to Excel.

Comment: How about CSV format?  Use string.Join(",", array);

Comment: it would be also helpful if it can be converted to System.Data.Datatable.

Comment: There's an example on Microsoft Docs to create Datatables or Datasets from a Linq query. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset

Comment: I've been working with another posting creating DataTable from query.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62373201/how-do-i-convert-dataset-to-model-t-for-excel-data-driven-tests/62415420#comment110693497_62415420